# Implementing Buttons In For Loop, Access Every Button Individually

Tags: angular

I am implementing an for-loop for the buttons, and on click the respective button color must change.

But in my case if I click on button, every button color is changing.

Comment: Need to add your effort till now. I mean show your code. Without code no one will help you.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/ , Iin case you are looking for a platform to upload your sample code

Answer (score 0):

I assume you must have some array having elements like this

```
colorArray = [
    {color: "red"},
    {color: "red"},
    {color: "red"},
    {color: "red"},
    {color: "red"}
  ]
```

In order to iterate. so you can chnage color on clicking on particular button like this

```
<div *ngFor = "let color of colorArray" >
        <div class = "col-md-3">
        <input type="button" (click)="changeColor(color)" value ="Delete" [style.background]='color?.color || "blue"' />
        </div>
   </div>

changeColor(clr) {
    clr.color = "blue";
  }
```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ylrejw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)